# Character creation limit?

Tags: disgaea-5

I've read somewhere (multiple websites; one from Gamefaqs, others are various sites) that the character limit is "a little over 100". May I ask what is the exact number of characters you can create? Are those from the DLC and Overlords that join you in battle counts as a deduction to the overall creation limit, especially the latter since they are basically recoloured versions of their perspective classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a post [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835980-disgaea-5-alliance-of-vengeance/72470978) the maximum is 111 generic characters. When added to the 17 unique characters, you get a maximum total number of characters of **128**.

> It appears there's a limit of 111 created characters. There's 17 story characters for a total of 128.

I'm not certain if DLC characters will count towards this 128, though. I never came close to that number of characters.

Comment: I would assume DLC/Bonus characters count aswell however this is based off from previous games like 2 and 4. no idea about D2 and 5. however given that 128 = 256/2 and i recall games using those kinds of numbers for memory purposes (like with the floor number in the mind of Harvest Moon) i would think that they wouldn't do 128 + [number of DLC] but rather if they wanted more than 128 character total they would then increase it to 256